# How to solve HttpRequestException while calling HttpClient PostAsync method to upload image

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are working on a chat app in xamarin ios native app and we want upload a image to server using HttpClient PostAsync() method, but its throw exception like

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host....

Our code to upload after select a image is..

```
public async void UploadToServer(string filePath, string filename, string fileExtension,long fileSize)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    using(var content= new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://*////");

        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = filePath
        };

        content.Add(fileContent);

        var result = await client.PostAsync("api/FileUpload?groupID =" + ChatDetaiils.groupID + "&memberID=" + UserLogin.userID + "&Message=File Test&chatType=File&FileName="+filename+"&fileSize="+fileSize+"&fileExtension="+fileExtension+"",content);

    }
}
```

We are using same code in our xamarin android native app and its working good in android.
We don't know what was my mistake. We are using visual studio for mac.

Please help to solve this or tell me another method to upload...

Comment: It seems that the phone can't contact the server.

Comment: `http:` Are you allowing non-trusted connections in your app's info.plist?

Comment: Please tell me key and value to add in info.plist

Comment: Are you added App Transport Security Settings in info.plist

Comment: I have added
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict> 
but its not working

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover my GetStringAsync() method working with http: but PostAsync() throw exception mention above. 
I have also added '<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/> </dict> ' in info.plist but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by just putting the right uri in base address.
`client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http:***.***.*.**");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get better results with this:

```cs
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "groupID", ChatDetaiils.groupID },
    { "memberID", UserLogin.userID },
    { "Message", File },
    // etc..etc
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var result = await client.PostAsync("api/FileUpload, content);
```

Comment: Hello Its solved by passing right uri..it was my mistake.
`client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http:***.***.*.**");`